# Progress Bar only loads first time. On second page it does not show

Tags: java, android, progress

Hello i have java code where progressBar Loads just for first time only.
second time when surfing inner pages it does not shows at all.

```
 package ext.packagename.apk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //open in webview
        //web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://example1.com");
        // opening in browser instead of WebView
        web.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("exmaple1.com") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example2.com") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example3.com") ) {
                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage("exit?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Progressbar is loading very fine at first time when main page loads. after that it disappear.

Comment: Because you set  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) in your onPageFinished method, set visibility to visible in onPageStarted method

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

in `onPageStarted` method